# I am not getting output its showing when i am call data from api ....type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'
E/flutter (27556): #0      new Rating.fromJson (package:flutter_fake_api/model/model.dart:52:17)
E/flutter (27556): #1      ProductService.fetchProducts.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_fake_api/services/service.dart:25:24)
E/flutter (27556): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:425:31)
E/flutter (27556): #3      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:354:26)
E/flutter (27556): #4      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
E/flutter (27556): #5      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
E/flutter (27556): #6      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:39:18)
E/flutter (27556): #7      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:224:7)
E/flutter (27556): #8      ProductService.fetchProducts (package:flutter_fake_api/services/service.dart:27:8)
E/flutter (27556): <asynchronous suspension>
```

output should be in container which contain title, image, price category, description ,rating
when call from api

Comment: Without providing a code is hard to point the exact error, but you have issue(s) with types.
API is returning one type, but the ``Rating.fromJson`` is expecting another (int & double). Provide the code and the data from the API, for more details.

Comment: Sample response required and the model that you used for parse

Comment: I use this  final List<Products> products = productsJson.map((productJson) => Products.fromJson(productJson)).toList();   
 insteed of return Products(
          id: e["id"],
          title: e["title"],
          price: e["price"],
          description: e["description"],
          category: e["category"],
          image: e["image"],
          rating: Rating.fromJson(e["rating"]),
        );
      }).toList();
and error gone

Answer (score 0):

Your Rating class like this :

```
Rating{
final double xyz;
}
```

Change Rating class like this :
double to int

```
 Rating{
final int xyz;
}
```

if this is not working then check api response and parameters datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
I use this  
final List<Products> products = productsJson.map((productJson) => 
Products.fromJson(productJson)).toList();   
insteed of 
return Products(
      id: e["id"],
      title: e["title"],
      price: e["price"],
      description: e["description"],
      category: e["category"],
      image: e["image"],
      rating: Rating.fromJson(e["rating"]),
    );
  }).toList();
and error gone
```

Comment: the answer is:
- unclear
- does not seem to answer the question
- not properly formated